# My code doesn't work as intended. Can you tell me why?

Tags: c, game-development, minimax, game-theory

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define SIZE 3

#define BOOLEAN int
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef enum {
    EMPTY = 0,
    PLAYER = 1,
    BOT = -1
} gridElement;

typedef enum {
    WIN = 1,
    LOSS = -1,
    DRAW = 0
} result;

typedef enum {
    EASY = 3,
    MODERATE = 5,
    HARD = 7,
    IMPOSSIBLE = 8
} difficultyLevel;

typedef struct move {
    int rowNum;
    int colNum;
} Move;

typedef gridElement board[SIZE][SIZE];

//utility function to find the maximum of two numbers
int max(int num1, int num2)
{
    if (num1 > num2)    
        return num1;
    return num2;
}

//utility function to find the minimum of two numbers
int min(int num1, int num2)
{
    if (num1 < num2)
        return num1;
    return num2;
}

//function to return the appropriate grid character corresponding to the grid element
char gridChar(gridElement gridValue)
{
    switch (gridValue)
    {
        case EMPTY:
            return '-';
        case PLAYER:
            return 'X';
        case BOT:
            return 'O';
        default:
            return '-';
    }
}

//function that outputs the current state of the game board.
void printBoard(const board state)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            printf("%c ", gridChar(state[i][j]));
        printf("\n");
    }
}

//utility function to check if the board is full or still has empty spaces left.
BOOLEAN isFull(const board state)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            if (state[i][j] == EMPTY)
                return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

BOOLEAN checkForWin(const board state, gridElement element)
{
    //Checking row elements
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (state[i][0] == element && state[i][1] == element && state[i][2] == element)
            return TRUE;
    }
    
    //Checking column elements
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (state[0][i] == element && state[1][i] == element && state[2][i] == element)
            return TRUE;
    }

    //Checking diagonal elements
    if (state[0][0] == element && state[1][1] == element && state[2][2] == element)
        return TRUE;

    if (state[2][0] == element && state[1][1] == element && state[0][2] == element)
        return TRUE;

    return FALSE;
}

int evaluateState(const board currentState)
{
    if (checkForWin(currentState, PLAYER))
        return WIN;

    if (checkForWin(currentState, BOT))
        return LOSS;

    return DRAW;        
}

//function to check if the game is over.
BOOLEAN isTerminalState(const board state)
{
    if (checkForWin(state, PLAYER) || checkForWin(state, BOT) || isFull(state))
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}

int minimax(board state, int depth, BOOLEAN isMaximizingPlayer)
{
    BOOLEAN isMinimizingPlayer = !isMaximizingPlayer;
    
    if (depth == 0 || isTerminalState(state))
        return evaluateState(state);

    int maxScore; int evalScore;
    if (isMaximizingPlayer)
    {
        maxScore = INT_MIN;

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            {
                if (state[i][j] == EMPTY)
                {
                    state[i][j] = BOT;
                    evalScore = minimax(state, depth - 1, FALSE);
                    state[i][j] = EMPTY;
                    maxScore = max(maxScore, evalScore);
                }
            }
        }
        return maxScore;
    }

    if (isMinimizingPlayer)
    {
        int minScore = INT_MAX;

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            {
                if (state[i][j] == EMPTY)
                {
                    state[i][j] = PLAYER;
                    evalScore = minimax(state, depth - 1, TRUE);
                    state[i][j] = EMPTY;
                    minScore = min(minScore, evalScore);
                }
            }
        }
        return minScore;
    }
    return 0;
}

BOOLEAN isValidMove(const board state, Move move)
{
    if (state[move.rowNum][move.colNum] != EMPTY)
        return FALSE;
    if (move.rowNum >= SIZE || move.colNum >= SIZE || move.rowNum < 0 || move.rowNum < 0)
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}

void makeMove(board state, Move move, gridElement element)
{
    state[move.rowNum][move.colNum] = element;
}

void botMove(board state, difficultyLevel depth)
{
    int bestMoveScore = INT_MIN; Move currentMove = {0,0}; Move bestMove = {0, 0};
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        currentMove.rowNum = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            currentMove.colNum = j;
            if (isValidMove(state, currentMove))
            {
                makeMove(state, currentMove, BOT);
                int currentMoveScore = -minimax(state, depth, FALSE);
                makeMove(state, currentMove, EMPTY);
                if (currentMoveScore > bestMoveScore)
                {
                    bestMoveScore = currentMoveScore;
                    bestMove = currentMove;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Game state after computer move\n");
    makeMove(state, bestMove, BOT);
}

void getPlayerMove(board state)
{
    int inputGridNum; Move playerMove; BOOLEAN isValid = FALSE;
    do {
        printf("Enter your move ");
        scanf_s("%d", &inputGridNum);
        playerMove.rowNum = (inputGridNum - 1) / 3;
        playerMove.colNum = (inputGridNum - 1) % 3;
        if (isValidMove(state, playerMove))
        {
            makeMove(state, playerMove, PLAYER);
            isValid = TRUE;
        }
    } while (!isValid);
}

/*void getPlayerMove(board state)
{
    char line[80];
    int inputGridNum;
    Move playerMove;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter your move [1-9] ");
        if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
            printf("End of file\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (sscanf(line, "%d", &inputGridNum) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid input\n");
            continue;
        }
        playerMove.rowNum = (inputGridNum - 1) / 3;
        playerMove.colNum = (inputGridNum - 1) % 3;
        if (!isValidMove(state, playerMove)) {
            printf("Invalid move\n");
            continue;
        }
        makeMove(state, playerMove, PLAYER);
        return;
    }
} */

int main()
{
    board state = {
        {EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY},
        {EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY},
        {EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY}
    };

    printBoard(state);

    int difficulty = IMPOSSIBLE;

    while (!isTerminalState(state))
    {
        getPlayerMove(state);
        printBoard(state);

        if (isTerminalState(state))
            break;

        botMove(state, difficulty);
        printBoard(state);
    }
    
    if (evaluateState(state) == WIN)
        printf("You win!");
    if (evaluateState(state) == LOSS)
        printf("You lose!");
    if (evaluateState(state) == DRAW)
        printf("The match is a tie!");
}
```

Original question :I tried making a tic-tac-toe game using minimax in C. When I run the code, I make my move first and then computer always plays the top-right corner. After that the computer doesn't make any other move as an response to my move. The game state after bot move prints the same state after the end of my move and then I'm asked to make my move again.

Update: I fixed the INFINITY constant and the code now works, but I'm able to beat the AI at times. I tried implementing the updated getPlayerMove() function as suggested by somebody below, but just including the <stdlib.h> library breaks the code. So still my code doesn't work as intended.

Comment: How are you trying to debug this? If you don't know how to use a debugger, add print-outs of the variables you are interested in to follow the program's progress.

Comment: Fwiw: `INFINITY` is the wrong constant to use since it's a `float`. `minScore` and `maxScore` are `int`s so use `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @Aravind, `maxScore = (int) - INFINITY;` --> `maxScore = INT_MIN;`

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code now works, but there is a small problem. I beat it, which shouldn't have been possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- `INFINITY` is a floating point constant, converting to type `int` does not produce the expected behavior. You should instead use `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` defined in `<limits.h>`.
- `scanf_s` is not portable. You should use `scanf()` or better read a line of input with `fgets()` and test for end of file, use `sscanf()` to convert the text and test for a successful conversion indicated by a return value of `1`.

Here is a modified version of `getPlayerMove`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>  // for exit function

#ifdef _MSC_VER
// disable compiler warning about insecure standard functions
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

void getPlayerMove(board state)
{
    char line[80];
    int inputGridNum;
    Move playerMove;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter your move [1-9] ");
        if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
            printf("End of file\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (sscanf(line, "%d", &inputGridNum) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid input\n");
            continue;
        }
        playerMove.rowNum = (inputGridNum - 1) / 3;
        playerMove.colNum = (inputGridNum - 1) % 3;
        if (!isValidMove(state, playerMove)) {
            printf("Invalid move\n");
            continue;
        }
        makeMove(state, playerMove, PLAYER);
        return;
    }
}
```